# RL Policy Gradient: How to deal with rewards that are strictly positive?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In short:

In the policy gradient method, if the reward is always positive (never negative), the policy gradient will always be positive, hence it will keep making our parameters larger. This makes the learning algorithm meaningless. How do we get around this problem?

---

In detail:

In "RL Course by David Silver" lecture 7 (on YouTube), he introduced the REINFORCE algorithm for policy gradient (here just showing 1 step):

[image]

The actual policy update is:

[image]

Note that v_t here stands for the reward we get. Let's say we're playing a game where the reward is always positive (eg. accumulating a score), and there are never any negative rewards, the gradient will always be positive, hence theta will keep increasing! So how do we deal with rewards that never change sign?

Answer (score 0):

Theta isn't one number, but rather a vector of numbers that parameterize your model. The gradient with respect to your parameter may be positive or negative. For example, consider that your parameters are just the probabilities for each action. They are constrained to add to 1.0. Increasing the probability of one action requires at least one of the other actions decrease in probability.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the formula there is also a log probability for the action which can be positive or negative. By doing policy gradients, the policy will increase or decrease the probability of doing a specific action under give states and the value function just gives **how much** the probability gonna to change. So it is totally fine all rewards are positive.